# Hypothesis Testing Question - Skittles

Tags: probability

Your friend claims he can tell the five colors of skittles apart by taste alone. The probability
of a skittle being any particular color is 1/5. You give your friend 3 skittles and he gets 2 correct. Should you believe him? What if you give him 100 and he gets 40 correct?

I have two approaches to this question: which one is correct?

1. We always expect him to average 20% accuracy. Therefore, we have reason to believe him in both of these scenarios, since the accuracy is well over 20%.
2. The probability of the first scenario happening (by the binomial probability formula) is (1/5)^2 * (4/5)^1 * 3C1 = 9.6%. The second scenario has probability .00023%. I actually don't know how to proceed from here. What do I compare these probabilities to in order to figure out if I should believe him or not?

Edit: If neither of these are correct/the best way of doing this, then what is?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should compare them with the $50\%$ mark, i.e. what actually happened was less likely to happen if he would be guessing randomly.

Comment: @Tavish Why would I compare with 50%, when it's not a 50-50 chance of being right/wrong?

Comment: Suppose I have a coin, and you claim to be able to guess what I flip every time. Suppose I flip it three times, and you guess the all the flips correctly. If you were guessing randomly, then this type of event should only happen with probability 1/8. Now say you guess 100 out of 100 flips correctly. If you were guessing randomly (i.e. had no ability to discern what the next flip would be), then we would expect a result like this with probability $1 / 2^{100}$. The explanation that you can predict the coin flips is in this sense more likely than randomly guessing the correct outcomes.

Comment: The probability of the first scenario happening would be 0.8 (for one wrong guess) *(0.2)^2(for 2 right guesses)*3(number of ways in which guesses could be ordered) whitch is about 9.6%

Comment: @Heroofmetal Thanks for the catch. I fixed that.

Comment: @Quotable That makes sense to me. So in my question, if he were guessing randomly, I would expect it with probability 9.6%. What do I take away from this?

Comment: What you can take from it is that ur friend has 9.6% chances of lying and 90.4% being right BUT you have to take in account that ur experimental sample is very small so variance is big, imagine if you get jackpot first try, it would be wrong to clam chances are 100%

Comment: @JamesFlanagin Imagine that you had many people playing the same game with you (say 100 of them). Then you would expect that if everyone were playing randomly 9-10 people would perform as according to the first scenario. 

With the second scenario, if 1,000,000 people played this game with you, you would expect ~ 2 people to exhibit the same level of performance (assuming everyone is playing randomly). 

If you believe your friend has no such skill, then he plays randomly. However, if he does something "impossible", then you can deduct he has some means by which he is performing well.

Comment: @Quotable Gotcha. Thank you so much. Lastly, what do you think about the point I made in my answer under "1." (the 20% thing). Is that valid?

Comment: @Heroofmetal This answer confuses me. Say that he got 80 guesses wrong and 20 right, the probability of this happening is 9.9%. By that logic, I would claim that he has a 9.9% chance of lying and 90.1% chance of telling the truth, right? Given that he only got 20% of his guesses right, why would I give a 90.1% chance that he is telling the truth (and can tell the colors apart by taste), when it's pretty obvious that that was just out of random luck??

Comment: The first approach is also a means by which to trust him; however you should be careful about this type of analysis. Suppose your friend plays the game once and guesses one skittle correctly. Then he has 100% accuracy (higher than the expected average of 20%). However with low sample sizes you have a very large variance, i.e. your friend's accuracy belongs to a large range of possible values. If your friend makes many many guesses, then the variance goes down, and it gives you a better idea of what his actual accuracy may be, allowing you to trust (or distrust) him more.